# typeorm: Select options for relationship

Tags: typeorm

My relationship ManyToMany gives me that result:

```
Project {
    name: 'Project1',
    users: [
        User{
            id: 1,
            name: 'John',
            email: 'john@johncompany.com'
         }
     ]
```

How can I select only `name` or `email` for my users?

Comment: Look at the query builder capability - you may be able to do this with subqueries...

Comment: @RichDuncan, thanks for your reply. I think this is what I need. But I can not figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decision:

```
.createQueryBuilder('project')
    .leftJoin('project.acc', 'acc')
    .addSelect(['acc.id', 'acc.name', 'acc.email', 'acc.pass', 'acc.lang'])
    .getMany()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also follow this method.

```
const query: any = await this.manager.createQueryBuilder(OrderProduct, 'orderProduct'); 
query.select('DISTINCT product_id as productId , created_date as CreatedDate');
query.orderBy('created_date', 'DESC')
return query.getRawMany();
```

Comment: Maybe it's working. I'll try use it later and let you know about results. Thanks for you answer!